# 4f Imaging System with cylindrical lenses

Tags: optics, lenses, imaging

I have seen an imaging system (4f) which uses two cylindrical lenses in a 4f configuration, but with an extra cylindrical lens at the fourier plane. How does this work?

Edit: Posting an image of the setup I am referring to:
We use a cylindrical lens L3b to perform a Fourier
transform in the horizontal x direction, and two additional
cylindrical lenses L3a and L3c to perform 4 f imaging in the vertical
y direction
[image: We use a cylindrical lens L3b to perform a Fourier transform in the horizontal x direction, and two additional cylindrical lenses L3a and L3c to perform 4 f imaging in the vertical y direction]

Comment: where have  you seen this?

Comment: https://opg.optica.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-45-20-5752

From this paper. I am not sure if you can access it, but I am wondering how does an extra lens at the Fourier plane of the 4f system work?

Comment: I am sorry I do not have access to that work; you should describe it in detail with at  least a drawing/image and you get *some* answers here.

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture and a short description they used in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what it is you don't understand exactly ?

The cylindrical lens focuses the light in only one direction (the one with the curved surface) while the other direction (flat surface) lets incoming light  unaltered. So you can de-couple the x and y axis. Having light focalised in one direction and collimated in the other.

A lens typically performs a Fourier Transform of a beam, so a cylindrical lens would only perform it in one direction. Try to draw the scheme for the XZ and YZ planes respectively.

Though the scheme provided seem incorrect as the beam should not focalise on camera but at f0 ?